# How to update data from observeValueForKeyPath frequently?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently fetching metadata for a internet radio station (artist name / track name / etc.) inside of a `observeValueForKeyPath` method. I am then taking that data and assigning it to a `UILabel`. The problem is that if I navigate to a previous view controller and come back, my label will now be empty until the `observeValueForKeyPath` kicks in again (which will be when there is a new song playing) so I have to wait for the current song to end and the next one to begin to get the metadata to update my label.

Is there a way to update/fetch data more frequently?

Comment: You can't get notifications more frequently than they're sent out, no. What object are you observing? Is there a `currentTrack` method available? Have you specified `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInital`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you fetching the metadata on `viewWillAppear`? Fetching metadata at that point should provide a value for that label at the appropriate time and not other times when it would be unnecessary work load.